# Issues with a function and its return value

Tags: php, function

I made this kind of point system, where users can spend their points. The users points do get deducted. I didn't include alot of the variables, but they are all okay. The problem occurs at `return($success)` and `return($error_message)`.

Here is the code:

```
function died($error) {
    header("Location: error_points_on.php?error=" . $error);
    die();
}

function success($success) {
    header("Location: success_points_on.php?success=" . $success);
    die();
}
function quote_smart($value, $handle) {

if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
$value = stripslashes($value);
}

if (!is_numeric($value)) {
$value = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($value, $handle) . "'";
}
return $value;
}

function product($price,$points, $name, $uname, $error_message, $success_message) {


    $user_name = "cencord";
    $pass_word = "cencord";
    $database = "cencord";
    $server = "cencord";

    $db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $pass_word);
    $db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);

 if ($db_found) { // connect to DB

            $uname = quote_smart($uname, $db_handle);
            $SQL = mysql_query("SELECT points FROM members WHERE username=$uname");
            $points = mysql_fetch_row($SQL);

            $points = $points[0]; // make it a variable rather then an array


    if ($points >= $price) {

         $points = $points-$price; // fjern points

         $points = quote_smart($points, $db_handle);

         mysql_query("UPDATE members SET points=$points WHERE username = $uname");

         $success_message .= "The " . $name . " has been mailed to your E-mail, please allow 5 minutes for it to arrive.<br />";
         return($success_message);
    }


        else if ($points < $price) {

        $error_message .= "You have " . $points . " you need " . $price . " points to purchase a " . $name;
        return($error_message);
        }

else if (!$db_found) {
$error_message .= "Could not connect to the database, please contact support";
return($error_message);
    }
}
}



  if($Checked1 == true) {
      product(400, $points, "Some string", $uname,     $error_message, $success_message); //price and name
}
  if($Checked2 == true) {

      product(400, $points, "Some string", $uname,     $error_message, $success_message);
}



 if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
 if(strlen($success_message) > 0) {
    success($success_message);
  }

echo "error didnt pass at all";
```

I could add the

```
header("Location: success_points_on.php?success=" . $success);
```

instead of a return, but I want the user to be able to purchase multiple items, (adding it instead of a return does work).

Comment: "the problem occurs"... can you explain what you intend to happen, and what is actually happening? "When I input x, I expect to see y, but I see z"?

Comment: I stated that below the code, sorry

"I could add the

header("Location: success_points_on.php?success=" . $success); 

instead of a return, but i want the user to be able to purchase multiple items, (adding it instead of a return does work).

Asked by Ivan R"

Comment: I am sorry but it is not clear what you intend to happen, and what is actually happening. Repeating the same thing doesn't generally make it clearer. "When I get to the line in my code that says "xxx", and the user is trying to do "yyy", then "zzz" happens. I want "qqq" to happen. Stating "adding it instead of a return does work" is not enough for a person who is willing to offer help for free, but isn't willing to decode you message. I am trying to help you get help...

Comment: I can elaborate, what i want, is 
A) user points get deducted from the SQL database (Works), 
B) user gets sent to apropriate error page with the apropriate $success_message / $error_message (Works if i send them there instantly rather then returning and checking for more items purchased).

What happens when that code is executed, is that 

echo "error didnt pass at all";

gets displayed, which is not supposed to get displayed since either $error_message or $success_message should contain a string

Comment: Sorry i forgot the quote_smart function, its not neccesary, but it should add some clarification, it is added now.

Comment: OK - that is helpful. When you call the function `product()`, you don't assign the return value to anything. Is that the problem?

Comment: yep ... that was the problem ... il have to remake the error / success system
thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Your logic nesting is wrong.  Stripping out the guts and leaving just the if statements, you have in your `product()` function:

```
function product($price,$points, $name, $uname, $error_message, $success_message) {
    if ($db_found) { // connect to DB
        if ($points >= $price) {
            $success_message = "blah";
            return($success_message);
        } 
        else if ($points < $price) {  // This if () part is redundant, btw
            $error_message = "blah";
            return($error_message);
        }
        else if (!$db_found) {
            $error_message .= "blah"; // This should be = instead of .=
            return($error_message);
        }
    }
}
```

What you want instead is:

```
function product($price,$points, $name, $uname, &$error_message, &$success_message) {
    if ($db_found) { 
        if ($points >= $price) {
            $success_message = "blah";
            return($success_message); // this is redundant actually
        } else {
            $error_message = "blah";
            return($error_message);  // this is redundant actually
        }
    } else {
        $error_message = "blah";
        return($error_message);  // this is redundant actually
    }
}
```

I would strongly recommend the use of some tool such as an IDE which can keep your code formatted correctly, this will make these types of problems easier to see.

EDIT

I also just noticed that you are not passing $error_message and $success_message by reference which will cause further problems.  Changes made above (in second example) but this code is still not what I would call best practice.

Comment: Looking in to how i can pass them by reference now ty

Comment: I did that already by adding the & in front of the parameter name :-)

Comment: Ty very much, i didnt know the variable did not get changed, and i didnt know about passing by reference, ty for the help, got it working now :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with everything @leftclickben said above, but would like to add one more observation. I seems that you are using the value of `$error_message` and `$success_message` in the code that follows your call to `product()`, but TO LET THE FUNCTION CHANGE THEIR VALUE, YOU MUST PASS THEM BY REFERENCE, using the `&` symbol.

Change your function prototype to

```
function product($price,$points, $name, $uname, &$error_message, &$success_message) {
```

and changes in the value will be available after the function returns.

Comment: Ty very much, i didnt know the variable did not get changed, and i didnt know about passing by reference, ty for the help, got it working now :)

Comment: @leftclickben - great minds think alike. I had not seen your edit, and you had not seen my post...